# Как сделать, чтобы код в ответах редактировался сам?

Tags: поддержка

Часто (почти всегда), давая ответ на вопрос, код пишется сразу, то есть не где-то в редакторе или IDE, а сразу вручную между тройных апострофов ```.

Возможно ли в таком случае сделать так, чтобы пробелы при открытии новой скобки ставились сами? Например, я пишу:

```
public class myClass {
    public void myMethod () {
        // здесь на каждой строке нужно ставить по 8 пробелов 
    }
}
```

Eсть ли способ, чтобы эти табуляции проставлялись сами после открытой фигурной скобки или там после двоеточия в питоне и т.п.?

Comment: Это вроде бы не задача сайта, сайт — не IDE. А писать код вслепую вообще плохо, у меня потом жутко бомбит когда я вижу неработающий код в ответах)

Comment: Безусловно, задача сайта в другом, но разве удобно ставить 8, 12, а то и 6 пробелов? `код вслепую  плохо` - мне кажется коды из ответов лучше не копировать, а переписывать, пытаясь понять смысл каждой строки. Ну в общем, вы хотите сказать, что такой возможности в StacKOverflow нет, правильно?

Comment: Можно написать расширение. ;)

Comment: [related](https://stackapps.com/questions/2209/se-editor-toolkit)

Comment: Напрашивается прикручивание какого-нибудь [ProseMirror+CodeMirror](https://prosemirror.net/examples/codemirror/) :)

Comment: @andreymal, сайт - не ide, но рабочий код - не цель ответа. Да и кому охота делать чужую работу? Автор вопроса должен прикладывать к решению проблемы как минимум 51% усилий от общего количества усилий затронутых людей. А если код должен быть на 100% рабочий, тогда надо прикручивать индикаторы [travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/status-images/) и [codecov](https://docs.codecov.io/docs/commit-status) к каждому ответу. Тогда (например, спустя сутки) можно автоматически удалять ответы с покрытием кода тестами меньше 80%!

Comment: @andreymal CodeMirror - прошлый век, в 2021 тренд в сторону [monaco-editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor) явно перевешивает по всем направлениям: качество кода, более проработанный и согласованный api и документация, количество языков подсветки, опережающий ввод, и даже базовые возможности рефакторинга, возможность подключить документацию по языку/библиотекам в подсказки по коду. Linter, подключённый к CM, даже близко не сравнится качеством анализа кода, разве что примитивные ошибки синтаксиса подчеркнет, когда в monaco проверяется даже орфография.

Comment: @DiD всё перечисленное нафиг не нужно на сайте, который не IDE. А рабочий код нужен.

Comment: @andreymal Ну как это не нужно? в CM код, api, документация оформленны просто отвратительно, и всё это при добавлении на страничку еще и не работает. Другой вопрос Monaco. Попробуйте в действии https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html . Там тоже не IDE, но всё работает. И даже чисто субъективно, у проекта больше звездей на github...

Comment: @DiD я ж уже написал - не нужно, потому что сайт это не IDE. Код/api/документация здесь вообще ни при чём.

Comment: @DiD вы считаете, что `качество кода, более проработанный и согласованный api и документация, количество языков подсветки, опережающий ввод, и даже базовые возможности рефакторинга` - это то, что нужно сайту прямо сейчас? Просто вопрос был про банальные отступы вместо ручных 4 пробелов:)

Comment: Не думал, что мой вопрос заведет в такие дебри... Я не знаю, как разрабатываются и работают расширения для StackOverflow, но мне кажется, что добавить автоматическое добавление табляции после открытой скобки - это не сложно. Хотя я не могу знать точно.